# DateAdapter is ignored when used in app component

Tags: angular

In my application, the user can change the language (FR/NL) in the top bar.

I'm using `mat-date-range-input` in some component, and wanted them to change languages aswell.

In the NgOnInit of `app.component.ts` :

```js
this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
  this.dateAdapter.setLocale(this.translateService.currentLang);
});
```

This doesn't do anything to the calendar, I still see the month in the default language when switching languages in the top bar.

However, when I put this code in the form component (with the datepickers), it works perfectly.

I guess I need to provide it but since DateAdapter is not assignable to type 'Provider', I don't see the solution.

Comment: Do you have following imported?
```import {MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material';```

```providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'es-ES' }]``` did you try this? Instead hard coding `useValue` try to insert your output from your service

Comment: @D.Ister Thanks for your answer, but can I use subscription in ```app.module.ts``` ?

Answer (score 0):

After going a little deeper into the project, I discovered that the provider was duplicated in another module, which I believe replaced my function's behavior in `app.component.ts`

```
{
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE],
}
```